# Forecasting using LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

How can I use Long Short-term Memory (LSTM) to predict a future value x(t+1) (out of sample prediction) based on a historical dataset. I read and tried many web tutorials for forecasting and prediction using lstm, but still far away from the point. What's the exact procedure to do this prediction? Is it just as simple as shifting the target array (n)steps where n is the number of future predicts and do the prediction operation? or there's another techniques? 
please help or leave a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide the framework you are using? tensorflow? pytorch? which web tutorials specifically?

Assuming you are going tensorflow, you can copy and paste code from one of  these, test that it works on the provided dataset, then modify the input encoding functions to fit your dataset, then run on your dataset.

https://github.com/llSourcell/How-to-Predict-Stock-Prices-Easily-Demo (best)

https://github.com/sebastianheinz/stockprediction

https://github.com/talolard/MarketVectors/blob/master/preparedata.ipynb (you will have to replace fc layers with lstm, and fiddle with inputs)

In general procedure is something like (assuming tensorflow):

1. Download Dataset
2. Create a function to load batches of data
3. Create a function to encode batch of data (normalization, other transforms)
4. Create LSTM layer to recieve series of inputs.
5. Create output layer (usually fully connected) to take last lstm state and predict output of your desired size.
6. Create a tf session to wire everything together, and hit run.

Some questions to ask conceptually about which network use:

How many inputs to how many outputs - see this excellent http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2016/winter1516_lecture10.pdf by Karpathy

How far back do you consider the stock prices eg {t-100... t} or {t-10 ...t} which may dictate size of hidden layers.

What other information do you think is relevant to the model? does stock A influence stock B? in which case you may have 2 lstms outputing a state to your fully connected layer...

Comment: I am using TensorFlow framework, I have no problem in predicting the testing data, can you please advice me how to predict a future value? i.e if i have 3000 rows in my dataset I am about to predict the value at row number 3001 , it can be done right?

I applied this tutorial :
http://www.python36.com/predict-cryptocurrency-price-using-lstm/
and this one : 
https://www.kaggle.com/jphoon/bitcoin-time-series-prediction-with-lstm

Comment: Ya off course it can be done. We would need to know - what does your data look like? What are the columns for each row - please post this in your question as it is part of Stackoverflows guidelines. Then, possibly modify input size of network. In the second link the output was day t+1 given days t-5 to t, so that can be changed to 300... how is this different from your question?

Comment: I think that I am not getting the entire picture of the prediction operation. May you please summarize what happened in the second tutorial after doing the model.fit() operation?